# Calling Fortran subroutine from C++, undefined reference when linking

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I've got a Fortran subroutine that I would like to call from a C++ program.  It takes a long list of floating-point arguments and uses the iso_c_binding intrinsic module:

```
subroutine parasolve ( ...... ) bind (c, name='c_parasolve')
  use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
....
```

Based on what I've read, I understand that I need to use C++'s "extern" command to define the external function before calling it later.  I tried it two ways.  The first:

```
extern "C" void c_parasolve( .... );
```

returns "expected unqualified-id before string constant" at compile time, whereas the second:

```
extern void c_parasolve( .... );
```

compiles just fine but fails to link with "undefined reference to 'c_parasolve( .... )'" and ld returns 1.

I'm compiling with:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

etc, and

```
gfortran -ffree-form -std=f2003 -c parasolve.f03
```

to get them into .o ELFs and then attempting to link with:

```
g++ main.o otherfiles.o parasolve.o -lgfortran
```

What is the proper way to call this Fortran function?

Comment: What are your command to compile and link this code?

Comment: I've edited it to show the commands

Comment: so i think you are getting the above error at first line.that is G++ -c main.cpp ????

Comment: The undefined reference error occurs when linking.  The "expected unqualified-id before string constant" occurs when compiling main.cpp with g++.  The fortran code compiles properly with gfortran.

Comment: try this g++ -c -std=c++0x -std=gnu++0x main.cpp -lgfortran

Comment: Same errors, didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `extern "C"` declaration is inside a function or class definition. This is not allowed -- it has to be at the top level in the source file. (Yes, the error message could be more informative!)

Comment: Thanks!  Feel like a doofus, thought it had to be declared in the same scope as where it was called.